# Search directory for files with specific string and print location

Tags: string, perl, file, search

I need to create a perl script that will search through a given directory and find all txt files that contain a specific string. I want the perl script to then print the location of those files. So far I have accomplished that task but I want to add a few more features to the script.

This is what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir ='C:\path\to\dir';
my $keyword = "apple";


find(\&txtsearch, $dir);

sub txtsearch {

   if(-f $_ && $_ =~ /\.txt$/) { 
       open my $file, "<", $_ or do {
           warn qq(Unable to open "$File::Find::name": $!); #checks permissions
           return;
       };

       while(<$file>) {
           if (/\Q$keyword\E/) {  
               print "$File::Find::name\n"; #prints location of file
               return; #stops searching once found             
           }
      }
   } 
}
```

Now I want to add a few things:
Firstly, I would like to include a way to include capitalization in the search. For example, if I want to find all the instances of the word "apple" I don't want it to overlook any uses of "Apple" or "APPLE".

I would also like to be apple to input the keyword in the command line rather then the actual script itself.

Also, would it be possible to have the script create a file in the specified directory named "output.txt" and have the output of the script import into that? I know one the command line you will have to have something like > output.txt but I am not completely sure how to implement that in the script.

Lastly, it would be nice if I could include a printout of how many occurrences of the string are in the file. For example, if the word "apple" appears 5 times in a text file, I would like to see an output of the location of the file and also, something like "apple appears 5 times in FILE.txt"

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I find the phrase "so far I have accomplished this task" coupled with perl 101 questions and the builtins and keywords used in your script to be both suspicious and amusing

Comment: On one hand, you are to be commended for trying to find a script that does what you want. On another hand, honestly admitting that you found someone else's script, but don't understand how it works at all and thus can't understand how to add even the most basic features would generate a lot more goodwill and less negative reactions.

Comment: I apologize, I did not mean to imply that I had wrote  the entire script by myself, I borrowed properties from several scripts that accomplished the same thing. My question was based on more about revising and adding more features to the script. I am a complete newbie and would like to learn perl and I understand the very basics but learn by examples. Any explanation of any feature of part of the script will be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much and sorry if I came off wrong!

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, I would like to include a way to include capitalization in the search. For example, if I want to find all the instances of the word "apple" I don't want it to overlook any uses of "Apple" or "APPLE".

Add `i` modifier to your regex

*Reference*: [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

> I would also like to be apple to input the keyword in the command line rather then the actual script itself.

Use [`GetOpt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) module for command line parameter processing.

*Reference*: [`GetOpt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

> Also, would it be possible to have the script create a file in the specified directory named "output.txt" and have the output of the script import into that? I know one the command line you will have to have something like > output.txt but I am not completely sure how to implement that in the script.

Open a file for writing using `open(my $output_filehandle, ">", "output.txt") or die "Can not open file for writing: output.txt. $!"`

Then replace `print <STUFF>` with `print $output_filehandle <STUFF>` .

*Reference*: [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [Tutorial on opening things in Perl on Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)

> Lastly, it would be nice if I could include a printout of how many occurrences of the string are in the file. For example, if the word "apple" appears 5 times in a text file, I would like to see an output of the location of the file and also, something like "apple appears 5 times in FILE.txt"

Keep a counter variable instead of returning after first hit. Then print filename and counter after file-lines loop ends.

*Reference*: Basic understanding of programming and loops, not really related to Perl at all.